# How do I stop already logged in user to login again using back button of the browser?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

In my online shop applications built in asp.net (C#) an already logged in user can again log in pressing back button to login page after giving correct username and password. How do I stop this?

My issue is: if a user is logged in successfully, then without logging out this current user, another user shouldn't be able to log in using back button to login page.

Note: though another user can login, the first user is logout automatically, there is no trespassing.

1. Anonymous user clicks on Login link and login.aspx page loads
2. Say, User "rk" logged in successfully typing his username and password
3. Now, "rk" clicks back-button of the browser
4. Again the login.aspx page loads
5. Now, when "rk" types username and password (as same username "rk" or say another username "rishi" and their password)
6. The new user successfully login("rk" or "rishi" which he typed as username with their pwd)

So, I want some mechanism to stop second user login and/or some message to display if there is already a logged in user who has not still logged out.

**Login.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Security;

public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }   
}
<br/ >

**Global.asax**   

<%@ Application Language="C#" %>

<script runat="Server">

void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{
    // Code that runs on application startup
}   

void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
//  Code that runs on application shutdown
}  

void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
// Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs
//Log all unhandled errors
Utilities.LogError(Server.GetLastError());
}

void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
// Code that runs when a new session is started
}

void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
// Code that runs when a session ends. 
// Note: The Session_End event is raised only when the sessionstate mode
// is set to InProc in the Web.config file. If session mode is set to StateServer 
// or SQLServer, the event is not raised.
}


</script>
<br />
```

Note: I've used Web Site Administration Tool  features of Visual Studio (i.e. ASP.NET Membership Provider)for creating "Admin" with administrator role and any other new user with customer role.

I am just a beginner's in asp.net  and trying to build e-commerce site with reference to "Cristene Daire" book help. Sorry for using layman terms .

Comment: You need to update this post to be clear and concise in describing what's happening.

Comment: One user is logging in and another use shouldn't be able to log in? So your site can be used by one user at a time only?

Comment: That's not what he's saying Thomas - he's just worded it a bit funny. Can you post your markup and code please RRK ?

Answer (score 0):

Check in login page if session still logged in then redirect to default page direct.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a logout command to your login page in case a logged in user loads the page.

If you only want to logout in case of another login, simply add the logout command to the submit form command.

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript to disable or hide the back button of the browser.